# Does washi tape stick on skin?

Tags: costume-design, makeup

I'm looking into putting together a Neil "Crazy" Craver costume. He is an athlete on American Ninja Warrior. He wears a lot of gold and decorates his chest and arms with gold stickers/temporary tattoos. Would washi tape stick to skin well enough to help me complete this look? I've never used washi tape, but I'm finding a bunch of great gold washi tape options online. Looking for opinions before I buy.

Image of Neil "Crazy" Craver for reference: https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-los-angeles-ca-usa-24th-aug-2016-neil-craver-at-arrivals-for-american-115890179.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: washi tape]
This is washi tape. I often keep some on hand. 
[image: on hand literally testing]
Ha ha, let’s test it on my hand. 
[image: upside down sticking]
It stays on for a while, but doesn’t bend like adhesive bandages. So, once the edge pops up, it is compromised. Sweat or moisture will not keep it on. Removing it once compromises it as well. It might stick for a while depending on movement.[image: edges lifted after moving tape]

Comment: Gotta love experimental verification! Good answer.